# 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc

while using POST using angularJS to the rest based controller in Spring MVC, I am getting 415 Media Type unsupported type. Can anybody please help in fixing the same.Below is the code for angularJS and Rest based controller.

AngularJS-

```
$http.post(urlBase + 'users/insert',$scope.user)
            .success(function(data) {
             $scope.users = data;   
             $scope.user="";
             $scope.toggle='!toggle';            
            });
```

Controller rest based -

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/users/insert",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
     public List<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) throws ParseException      { 
       //setter methods for setting objects and sending to backend
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, have set some default value to due to which this issue was coming.  `$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`

Corrected it to-
`$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";`

Answer (score 0):

For spring-mvc JSON-Java conversion, you need to have jackson libraries in your classpath

```
<dependency> 
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

For more detailed example look at this [link](http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java/)

Comment: No @Ramesh Ponnada, I tried but still, it show the same issue.